# Dropping rows fast from a multi-indexed data frame conditional on the level 1 index

Tags: python, pandas

I have problems dropping rows in a quick way from a multiindexed pandas data frame where the dropping criterion is based on the level 1 index. Or equivalently, building up a multiindexed data frame by appending single-indexed data frames or numpy arrays as the rows. In my concrete example, I have a data frame called "watch" such as this:

```
                             userid   watchers
repositoryid         date       
     5910995   1348293168   1449180          1
     5911012   1348292421   2627657          1
     5911046   1367171000   1219404          1
               1368722792   1892225          2
               1383586883   2150178          3
     5911088   1348302179   1521780          1
         ...
```

where repositoryid and date are the levels 0 and 1 of a multiindex, respectively, and userid and watchers are the data columns. So, for every repositoryid, I basically have a time series of events of users who start watching a repository. For each repositoryid, I also know a specific creationdate from somewhere else. Now I want to drop all rows where date > creationdate+timewindow, where timewindow is some constant.

I tried using the drop() function, but that was extremely slow. I thought boolean masking would be the best solution, but I was not able to make it work with the multiindex. I also tried building up a new data frame from scratch in several attempts, the latest one is this:

```
watch_new = DataFrame(columns=['date', 'userid', 'watchers'])
for i,rid in enumerate(watch.index.get_level_values('repositoryid')):
    creationdate = repository.loc[rid].date.squeeze()
    thistimeseries = watch.loc[rid]
    thistimeseries = thistimeseries[thistimeseries.index <= creationdate+timewindow]
    thistimeseries.reset_index(inplace=True)
    if len(thistimeseries) != 0:
        watch_new.loc[rid] = thistimeseries.as_matrix()
```

Unfortunately, as soon as thistimeseries.as_matrix() has more than one row, I receive an error message such as this (in this case, 10 rows):

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,3) into shape (3)
```

So, my question is, 1a) how do I drop rows quickly from a multi-indexed data frame conditional on the level 1 index, or equivalently 1b) how do I insert single-indexed data frames into multi-indexed data frames, and 2) is this even the best=fastest way to solve my problem, or should I try a completely different approach?

(I also tried to not use indices, but that was too slow. I played around with join, merge, groupby, etc, unfortunately I did not manage to get them to solve my issue. I spent the last 5 days studying the excellent book "Python for Data Analysis" and trying to find solutions online to this problem, again without success. I hope that maybe an advanced pandas user has an elegant solution to this seemingly simple issue? Thanks a lot in advance!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this setup:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+').set_index(['repositoryid', 'date'])
repository = pd.read_table('data2', sep='\s+').set_index(['repositoryid'])
timewindow = 100
```

Suppose we have `df`:

```
                          userid  watchers
repositoryid date                         
5910995      1348293168  1449180         1
5911012      1348292421  2627657         1
5911046      1367171000  1219404         1
             1368722792  1892225         2
             1383586883  2150178         3
5911088      1348302179  1521780         1
```

and `repository`:

```
                    date
repositoryid            
5910995       1348293200
5911012       1348292400
5911046       1368722800
5911088       1348303000
```

Currently, Pandas does not support merging on only certain levels of a MultiIndex. So both `df` and `repository` have to have the same index shape in order to be merged:

```
df.reset_index(level='date', inplace=True)
df = df.join(repository, rsuffix='_threshold')
```

yields

```
                    date   userid  watchers  date_threshold
repositoryid                                               
5910995       1348293168  1449180         1      1348293200
5911012       1348292421  2627657         1      1348292400
5911046       1367171000  1219404         1      1368722800
5911046       1368722792  1892225         2      1368722800
5911046       1383586883  2150178         3      1368722800
5911088       1348302179  1521780         1      1348303000
```

Now you can add the `timewindow` to `date_threshold`:

```
df['date_threshold'] += timewindow
```

and compare when the `date` is less than the `date_threshold`:

```
mask = df['date'] < df['date_threshold']
```

which yields a boolean Series like

```
In [207]: mask
Out[207]: 
repositoryid
5910995          True
5911012          True
5911046          True
5911046          True
5911046         False
5911088          True
dtype: bool
```

Using the boolean Series it is easy to select the desired rows using `df.loc`:

```
In [208]: df.loc[mask]
Out[208]: 
                    date   userid  watchers  date_threshold
repositoryid                                               
5910995       1348293168  1449180         1      1348293300
5911012       1348292421  2627657         1      1348292500
5911046       1367171000  1219404         1      1368722900
5911046       1368722792  1892225         2      1368722900
5911088       1348302179  1521780         1      1348303100
```

Alternatively, instead of using `mask` and `df.loc`, you could use `query`:

```
In [213]: df.query('date < date_threshold')
Out[213]: 
                    date   userid  watchers  date_threshold
repositoryid                                               
5910995       1348293168  1449180         1      1348293300
5911012       1348292421  2627657         1      1348292500
5911046       1367171000  1219404         1      1368722900
5911046       1368722792  1892225         2      1368722900
5911088       1348302179  1521780         1      1348303100
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I guess I will try to avoid working with multi-indices for now, as they seem to be a bit limited.